# getting limited records from amazon api : ListMatchingProductsSample.php

Tags: php

I am getting 10 records of product from my amazon store using amazon MWS api :: " ListMatchingProductSample.php" . I want to fetch all the products from my store through amazonMWS api .Products in my store are around 900. How can i get all the product details.
Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks
swastika